# unable to click on UIAStaticText using appium on ios

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

unable to click on UIAStaticText using appium on ios

Please help me to click in label using appium on ios app.

Answer (score 0):

click on UIAStacticText is similar to any other element click. Why you want to click on static text anyways? Do you want to launch any hover window or scroll?

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAWebView[1]/UIAStaticText[@name='Your element name']"));
element.click();
```

Your x-path can vary according to your app though.

Answer (score 0):

If the direct element.click() is not working, try using the precise tap option.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    HashMap<String, Double> tapObject = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    tapObject.put("x", x);
    tapObject.put("y", y);
    tapObject.put("duration", 1.0);
    tapObject.put("touchCount", 1.0);
    tapObject.put("tapCount", 1.0);

    js.executeScript("mobile: tap", tapObject);
```

Hope this helps.